# EmguCV Tracker implementation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, emgucv

Looking for example code to understand how to implement EmguCV tracker. I tried few things like in this poorly written code:

```
class ObjectTracker
{
Emgu.CV.Tracking.TrackerCSRT tracker = new Emgu.CV.Tracking.TrackerCSRT();
bool isActive = false;
public bool trackerActive = false;
public void Track(Bitmap pic, Rectangle selection,out Rectangle bound)
{   
    Rectangle result = new Rectangle();
    Bitmap bitmap=pic; //This is your bitmap
    Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> imageCV = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap); //Image Class from Emgu.CV
    Emgu.CV.Mat mat = imageCV.Mat; //This is your Image converted to Mat

    if (tracker.Init(mat,selection))
    {
        while (tracker.Update(mat, out bound))
        {
           result = bound;
        }
    }
    bound = result;     
}
```

I'm aware of there is few logic flaws, but still I couldn't menage to get any result in different attempts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it is really simple.

First define a Tracker in a type you desire.

Example:

```
Emgu.CV.Tracking.TrackerCSRT Tracker= new Emgu.CV.Tracking.TrackerCSRT();
```

Then before scaning the selected area(RoI) you need to initialize tracker

Example:

```
Tracker.Initimage, roi);
```

Important Note: image must be in type of  Emgu.CV.Mat , roi Drawing.Rectangle.
To convert your Bitmap to Mat you can use following method:

Example:

```
public Emgu.CV.Mat  toMat(Bitmap pic)
{
Bitmap bitmap=pic; 
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> imageCV = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap); 
Emgu.CV.Mat mat = imageCV.Mat; 
return mat;
}
```

Note: This code belongs to someone else from stackoverflow which I forget the source. Thanks to him/her.

Finally using following statement will returns Rectangle that envelopes tracked object. Trick is object doesn't return Rectangle as method output, it returns it via out statement.

```
tracker.Update(image, out roi);
```

Last Note: If anyone knows how to improve performance or multithread this method, please leave a comment.

Have a nice day!